# “wlan0: carrier lost” untimtly WiFi deconection on raspberry pi 3b+ and pi0 W

Tags: wifi, linux, python-3, raspbian-lite, raspberry-pi-os-buster

I am facing this bug since few days.

I am using: Rpi 3b+ or Rpi0W, Buster-lite with last update, Kernel : 4.19.118+

I using Ubiquti WiFi AP and dnsmasq for managing the lan, both working normally with other machines (debian), The Wifi RSSI Signal is very good for Rpis, The bug is happening only during the day untimely, I have running a script which do http Requests on the web (python).

I have tried several solution found in forums: Disabled Power_save option, wpa_cli scanning every 120 scds, pinging each two second,

After Wifi lost, Rpi reconnect but it can take more than few minutes. Any ideas ? How to resolve this ?

```
    Jul 30 14:44:54 raspi6 dhcpcd[376]: wlan0: carrier lost
Jul 30 14:44:54 raspi6 dhcpcd[376]: wlan0: deleting address fe80::5260:eec7:70e2:5716
Jul 30 14:44:54 raspi6 avahi-daemon[241]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::5260:eec7:70e2:5716 on wlan0.
Jul 30 14:44:54 raspi6 avahi-daemon[241]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::5260:eec7:70e2:5716.
Jul 30 14:44:54 raspi6 avahi-daemon[241]: Interface wlan0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jul 30 14:44:54 raspi6 avahi-daemon[241]: Withdrawing address record for 10.200.206.163 on wlan0.
Jul 30 14:44:54 raspi6 avahi-daemon[241]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 10.200.206.163.
Jul 30 14:44:54 raspi6 avahi-daemon[241]: Interface wlan0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jul 30 14:44:54 raspi6 dhcpcd[376]: wlan0: deleting route to 10.200.0.0/16
Jul 30 14:44:54 raspi6 dhcpcd[376]: wlan0: deleting default route via 10.200.0.1
Jul 30 14:45:41 raspi6 dhcpcd[376]: wlan0: carrier acquired
Jul 30 14:45:41 raspi6 dhcpcd[376]: wlan0: IAID eb:22:68:39
Jul 30 14:45:41 raspi6 dhcpcd[376]: wlan0: adding address fe80::5260:eec7:70e2:5716
Jul 30 14:45:41 raspi6 avahi-daemon[241]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::5260:eec7:70e2:5716.
Jul 30 14:45:41 raspi6 avahi-daemon[241]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jul 30 14:45:41 raspi6 avahi-daemon[241]: Registering new address record for fe80::5260:eec7:70e2:5716 on wlan0.*.
Jul 30 14:45:41 raspi6 dhcpcd[376]: wlan0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Jul 30 14:45:41 raspi6 dhcpcd[376]: wlan0: carrier acquired
Jul 30 14:45:41 raspi6 dhcpcd[376]: wlan0: IAID eb:22:68:39
Jul 30 14:45:41 raspi6 dhcpcd[376]: wlan0: adding address fe80::5260:eec7:70e2:5716
Jul 30 14:45:41 raspi6 avahi-daemon[241]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::5260:eec7:70e2:5716.
Jul 30 14:45:41 raspi6 avahi-daemon[241]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jul 30 14:45:41 raspi6 avahi-daemon[241]: Registering new address record for fe80::5260:eec7:70e2:5716 on wlan0.*.
Jul 30 14:45:41 raspi6 dhcpcd[376]: wlan0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Jul 30 14:45:47 raspi6 dhcpcd[376]: wlan0: probing for an IPv4LL address
Jul 30 14:45:47 raspi6 dhcpcd[376]: wlan0: DHCP lease expired
Jul 30 14:45:47 raspi6 dhcpcd[376]: wlan0: soliciting a DHCP lease
Jul 30 14:45:52 raspi6 dhcpcd[376]: wlan0: using IPv4LL address 169.254.69.244
Jul 30 14:45:52 raspi6 avahi-daemon[241]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 169.254.69.244.
Jul 30 14:45:52 raspi6 dhcpcd[376]: wlan0: adding route to 169.254.0.0/16
Jul 30 14:45:52 raspi6 dhcpcd[376]: wlan0: adding default route
Jul 30 14:45:52 raspi6 avahi-daemon[241]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Jul 30 14:45:52 raspi6 avahi-daemon[241]: Registering new address record for 169.254.69.244 on wlan0.IPv4.
Jul 30 14:45:54 raspi6 dhcpcd[376]: wlan0: no IPv6 Routers available
Jul 30 14:46:15 raspi6 dhcpcd[376]: wlan0: offered 10.200.206.163 from 10.200.0.1
Jul 30 14:46:15 raspi6 dhcpcd[376]: wlan0: probing address 10.200.206.163/16
Jul 30 14:46:20 raspi6 dhcpcd[376]: wlan0: leased 10.200.206.163 for 3600 seconds
Jul 30 14:46:20 raspi6 avahi-daemon[241]: Registering new address record for 10.200.206.163 on wlan0.IPv4.
Jul 30 14:46:20 raspi6 dhcpcd[376]: wlan0: adding route to 10.200.0.0/16
Jul 30 14:46:20 raspi6 dhcpcd[376]: wlan0: changing default route via 10.200.0.1
Jul 30 14:46:20 raspi6 avahi-daemon[241]: Withdrawing address record for 169.254.69.244 on wlan0.
Jul 30 14:46:20 raspi6 avahi-daemon[241]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 169.254.69.244.
Jul 30 14:46:21 raspi6 avahi-daemon[241]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 10.200.206.163.
Jul 30 14:46:20 raspi6 avahi-daemon[241]: Withdrawing address record for 169.254.69.244 on wlan0.
Jul 30 14:46:20 raspi6 avahi-daemon[241]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 169.254.69.244.
Jul 30 14:46:21 raspi6 avahi-daemon[241]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 10.200.206.163.
```

Comment: The log does not help much. It only shows what `dhcpcd` and `avahi-daemon` is doing when a carrier is lost or gotten. There is normal action shown. What command to you use? Look what `wpa_supplicant` is doing with `journalctl --boot --unit=wpa_supplicant.service` and add this output instead.

Comment: I have only this for **journalctl --boot --unit=wpa_supplicant.service** 
`-- Logs begin at Mon 2020-08-17 16:03:32 CEST, end at Mon 2020-08-17 17:08:05 CEST. --
-- No entries --`

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with your setup. On an unmodified **Raspberry Pi OS Buster Lite** I get: `-- Logs begin at Mon 2020-08-17 19:43:04 BST, end at Mon 2020-08-17 19:44:49 BST. --
Aug 17 19:43:07 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting WPA supplicant...
Aug 17 19:43:08 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[488]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Aug 17 19:43:08 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started WPA supplicant.`

Comment: you are right, the result above come from buster full OS, from buster lite i have :
`-- Logs begin at Wed 2020-08-05 15:17:01 CEST, end at Tue 2020-08-18 09:44:44 CEST. --
Aug 05 15:17:15 raspberrypi1 systemd[1]: Starting WPA supplicant...
Aug 05 15:17:16 raspberrypi1 wpa_supplicant[248]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Aug 05 15:17:17 raspberrypi1 systemd[1]: Started WPA supplicant.`
But the bug is the same in all buster version full, normal, and lite buster

Comment: Between an unmodified RaspiOS Lite and Full version there is no difference in networking. The Full version should give the same output. It seems the default systemd service management is broken on your system. This may give you problems.

Comment: In fact, i have disabled Bluetooth by adding this to the end of file  **/boot/config.txt** `enable_uart=1
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt`

Comment: In fact, i have disabled Bluetooth by adding this to the end of file  **/boot/config.txt** `enable_uart=1
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt`
Consequently i have disabled Bluetooth service `sudo systemctl disable hciuart.service`
I have enable it again et rebooted, then i have a this output `-- Logs begin at Tue 2020-08-18 17:26:58 CEST, end at Tue 2020-08-18 17:29:01 CEST. --
raspi6NOS systemd[1]: Starting WPA supplicant...
raspi6NOS wpa_supplicant[273]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
raspi6NOS systemd[1]: Started WPA supplicant.`
I will test with this configuration, and post again.

Comment: It is a little bit strange, when i am just rebooting the output of **journalctl --boot --unit=wpa_supplicant.service** is ok `-- Logs begin at Wed 2020-08-19 14:43:30 CEST, end at Wed 2020-08-19 14:45:00 CEST. --
Aug 19 14:43:49 raspi6NOS systemd[1]: Starting WPA supplicant...
Aug 19 14:43:50 raspi6NOS wpa_supplicant[282]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Aug 19 14:43:52 raspi6NOS systemd[1]: Started WPA supplicant.`
after some times the output became "wrong" ? `-- Logs begin at Wed 2020-08-19 13:47:20 CEST, end at Wed 2020-08-19 14:43:23 CEST. --
-- No entries --`

Comment: Maybe the filter option of `journalctl` isn't set correct? Look at `journalctl --help` and try only `journalctl` and search for `wpa_supplicant`.

Comment: The RTC clock is not set, may the problem came from here ?
`pi@raspi7FOS:~ $ timedatectl show
Timezone=Europe/Paris
LocalRTC=no
CanNTP=yes
NTP=yes
NTPSynchronized=yes
TimeUSec=Wed 2020-08-19 17:26:13 CEST`

Comment: Actually i am looking inside **syslog** to know what happening. concerning **wpa_supplicant** i have increased verbosity with **sudo wpa_cli log_level debug** because there nothing about it. Concerning **/etc/systemd/journald.conf** all thing are commented inside, i never modified this file.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://weigu.lu/sb-computer/raspi_tips_tricks/, you can try disabling the power_save

Command to read the current power saving mode (Stretch):
$ sudo iw wlan0 get power_save

Command to power_save off:
$ sudo iw wlan0 set power_save off

To make this permanent add the following line to /etc/rc.local:
$ sudo /sbin/iw dev wlan0 set power_save off